# Install package modules for Linter package in Atom

Tags: git, installation, package, atom-editor

I'm using [the Atom text editor](https://atom.io/), and have installed the the '[Linter](https://atom.io/packages/linter)' package so I can get realtime debugging/error reports when editing.

Atom has an UI for auto-installing packages - one-click installs, so I have no idea how to do it manually.

I'm very new to Git, and coding in general, so the installation instructions in the documentation for this package are not very helpful (for me).

Basically, I'm trying to install/run/get PHP validation going when I'm using Atom text editor. How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The official [documentation for installing packages is here](https://atom.io/docs/latest/customizing-atom):

([Since March 2015](http://blog.atom.io/2015/03/11/atom-docs.html), there is an [official repo](https://github.com/atom/docs) for the [**Atom.io doc**](https://atom.io/docs/latest/))

> You can also install packages from the command line using apm.
>
> Check that you have apm installed by running the following command in your terminal:

```
apm help install
```

You should see a message print out with details about the apm install command.

> If you do not, launch Atom and run the `Atom > Install Shell Commands` menu to install the `apm` and atom commands.

---

> You can also install packages by using the **`apm install`** command:

```
apm install <package_name> to install the latest version.

apm install <package_name>@<package_version> to install a specific version.
```

> For example `apm install emmet@0.1.5` installs the `0.1.5` release of the `Emmet` package into `~/.atom/packages`.
>
> You can also use apm to find new packages to install:

```
apm search coffee to search for CoffeeScript packages.

apm view emmet to see more information about a specific package.
```

---

Regarding the manual installation of a package in Atom, [this thread mentions](http://discuss.atom.io/t/manually-install-package/9251)

> You can download the package, unzip or decompress, go to that folder and run: `apm link` that will create a symbolic link from that package to your `~/.atom/packages` folder
>
> The repo can be found via the "Learn More"-button in the package manager.

In your case:

- repo https://github.com/AtomLinter/linter-phpcs,
- with archive available at https://github.com/AtomLinter/linter-phpcs/archive/master.zip

You find a similar process in [this thread](http://discuss.atom.io/t/how-to-setup-development-for-core-modules-like-atom-keymap/9221/4):

> 1. Make sure I do not have module installed already.
> 2. `git clone https://github.com/AtomLinter/linter-phpcs` to ~/Projects/
> 3. `apm link --dev` while being inside of `~/Projects/linter-phpcs`.
>      It successfully created symlink in `~/.atom/dev/packages/linter-phpcs`
> 4. Open atom using "atom --dev" command while being in `~/.atom/dev/packages/linter-phpcs`

Comment: Thanks for your response, VonC - That's still going over my head, unfortunately. I'll need something far more specific - assume you're talking to the technically challenged i.e. download this, place here, open that, type this etc. The less jargon, the better. Also - I didn't specifically say, but I'm using a Mac.

Comment: @Colly Ok. First, did you download https://github.com/AtomLinter/linter-phpcs/archive/master.zip?

Comment: yes, downloaded and on my desktop. I also have MAMP installed, which I understand had latest version of PHP included.

Comment: @Colly did you uncompress the archive , go the uncompresed folder, and run `apm link`?

Comment: uncompressed OK, but then you lose me. In the folder there's a README.md, package.json, 'lib' folder with init.coffee and liner-phpcs.coffee. 
Can't see 'amp link'?

Comment: @Colly "run `apm link`" means type "`apm link`" followed by return, in order to execute the command `apm` with the parameter `link`. (note, it is `apm`, not `amp`)

Comment: thank you for the update - turns out shell commands wasn't installed - commands in terminal works now! packages installed OK. Thanks very much for your time and effort.